# Data type conversion Issue in calculation Using Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select (1/4)
```

result is

```
0
```

I need actual result that is .025.And i tried like this

```
select (1/4.0)
```

and i got the actual result that is

```
0.2500000
```

i have more calculations function sometimes the result is not correct because of this issue.please Suggest any permanent solution for this issue.

Comment: Yes, you have to be aware of the data types of values you're using in calculations. I don't think there's a *technical* solution to this, it's just a reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2 digit precision, try this:

```
ROUND(AVG(CAST((1/4.0) as float)), 2)
```

For 3 digit precision:

```
ROUND(AVG(CAST((1/4.0) as float)), 3)
```

etc.

Comment: but i have lot of functions so it is so difficult to me.otherwise any other options?

Comment: What do you mean a lot of functions ? This is the proper way to get 2 point precision for float...

Answer (score 0):

you also can use

```
select cast(1/4.0 as numeric(3,2))
```